# Creating functions using chef client 13.4.19

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

We have a requirement to create 20 users and add those users (not all the user )to required servers.How to accomplish this using chef recipe.Definitions are not supported in chef 13.4.19.

Server1 :- a,b,c
Server2 :- b,d,e
server3 :- f,g,h

Note:- a to h are denoting users.

Single user recipe

```
user "xxxxx" do
  manage_home  true
  comment "admin"
  uid 10001
  gid "yyyyyyy"
  shell "/bin/bash"
  home "/home/xxxxx"
end
directory "/home/xxxxx/.ssh" do
   owner "xxxxx"
   group "xxxxx"
   mode "0700"
end
file "/home/xxxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys" do
   #source "authorized_keys_xxxxx"
   content 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nsldjflsjdflhsdjflsldflsjdf5KksjfxvmzbcmzxbcmzxbcsjdjshdkjsweyriewyiyweifhskdjhfisdfksdjhfisdhfkjsbvmxcvksdfhksdncksdhfkjxchvisdhfsdkvcyisdhvksdhcvisdhcisdfwieyirweuyriweyriwueyriweuhkcxvbbcvkxbcvksxviusdyfisdfyiCHrtfF5BX936vhPSrwgSbGJ48DKIxquib5ZYrjK9KyUNNrrg19wl5TW xxxxx_rsa.pub@Macbook-pro'
   owner "xxxxx"
   group "xxxxx"
   mode "0600"
end
```

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You would usually want to make a [custom resource](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) describing all the things that go in to a user, and then probably some recipe code like this:

```
my_user 'a' do
  uid 1234
  ssh_key 'whatever'
  # Other stuff here
  only_if { %w{server1.example.com server2.example.com}.include?(node['fqdn']) }
end
```

Or something like that, you can also use conditional actions instead of an `only_if`.

Comment: Can you provide an example for custom resource for my_user.

Comment: Not really, it depends entirely on what kinds of things you want to do when creating users.

Comment: Update question section for  user details .

Comment: Okay, just look at the docs I linked and put those three resources in the action.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Appreciate your help.